# which of these controls: UITableViewController or UIViewController should i choose?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, xcode4, uitableview

I'm trying to achieve the following (the colors are just to define the sections clearly)
[image]

can you please advise which of the two controllers (UITableViewController or UIViewController) i should use as well as should each "color" be a section or a cell/row

thank you!

Comment: to whom ever decided to downgrade this question,**you are promoting the shyness** of people to ask questions that to you seem obvious but to new-bees like me serve as stepping stone to better understand xcode and iphone programming, so congratulate yourself on that!

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController would be suitable if you had more generic rows. What you should do is simply add a few sub views to an UIViewController.